# how to erase negative ticks from NVD3 line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I tried to erase negative ticks from my NVD3 line chart (with data includes 0 only)
but It seems impossible what I wanted to do...

I want to set the line bottom when I throw data what includes 0 only.
Is there another way? or just I had a mistake?

code:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
    //DATA.B includes only 0 data, the value must be "data>0"
    data = DATA.A,DATA.B;

    var chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
        .margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 70})
        .x(function(d,i) { return i })
        .y(function(d,i) { return d[1] });

    chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
        var dx = data[0].values[d] && data[0].values[d][0] || 0;
        return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d')(new Date(dx))
    });

    chart.y1Axis
         .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'))
         .tickSize(0,6);
    chart.y2Axis
         .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.format(',f')(d) + '%' });
    chart.bars.forceY([0]);
    d3.select($node).datum(data).transition().duration(0).call(chart);
    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    return chart;
});
```

thanks

Comment: this code creates line on the middle of chart, I thought I should add something to "chart.y1Axis"

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle/Plunker please? Difficult to diagnose without seeing data you're passing in. Also why have you done  data = DATA.A,DATA.B; 

That code will not do what the comment above indicates.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I'll prepare it asap.